# How to prevent creating a new line in this tiny Python code I've done?

Tags: python-3.x

I made a python script that receives user input and prints every letter one by one every second.

The problem is it creates a new line for every letter, and I don't want that.

Here is the code:

```
import time

# Ask for the string, convert it to uppercase, and count the total characters in the string and say it.
def main():
    sent = input("Enter a 20 letter string:\n")
    sent = sent.upper()
    chars = 0
    if len(sent) > 20:
        sent = input("Enter a 20 letter string (Only 20 characters allowed):\n")
        main()
    else:
        for i in sent:
            print(sent[chars])
            time.sleep(1)
            chars += 1
        exit()
main()
```

I tried the `end=""`in `print()` as well and then it doesn't print out the letters one by one anymore but instead, it pauses for some seconds (Depends on how long the string is) and then it spits out the user input at the very last minute.

Comment: `end=""` will work. Try `print(sent[chars], end="", flush=True)` to ensure that everything gets printed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def main():
sent = input("Enter a 20 letter string:\n")
sent = sent.upper()
chars = 0

if len(sent) > 20:
    sent = input("Enter a 20 letter string (Only 20 characters allowed):\n")
    main()
else:
    for i in sent:
        print(sent[chars], end= "", flush= True)
        time.sleep(1)
        chars += 1
    exit()
main()
```

It works with end="" and flush set to True.